# Android Camera - Half of the screen is black in Portrait mode

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I was trying to create camera app, but I have faced this issue : when using camera in landscape mode everything is OK, but using in portrait with setDisplayOrientation(90) method brings up this issue:

Half of the screen is black.

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPTex.jpg

surfaceCreated method:

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            this.camera = Camera.open();
            this.camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(this.holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/analyzeButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/analyze" />
</LinearLayout>
```

By the way, in screenshots taken with ADB - camera is shown normally.
Tested on Xperia ST27i an Samsung Galaxy Pocket - same results.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
// The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to draw.
mCamera = Camera.open();

Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{
params.set("orientation", "portrait");
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}

try
{
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
}
catch (IOException exception)
{
mCamera.release();
mCamera = null;
}

}
```

try these code friend  ......................